# Why do "google.com/images", and "google.com////////////images" go to the same webpage?

Tags: html

Basically, when we want to visit a sub webpage within a domain, we add a slash, and then enter the name. But something I noticed is that it doesn't matter how many slashes you add, it still redirects to the one you want?

Why?

```
google.com/images = google.com///////images
https://stackoverflow.com == https://///////////////stackoverflow.com
```

Is this something with all websites, and if so, does it automatically happen?

Comment: If you're running a UNIX-like OS try the following:

`ls -l .`
`ls -l .//////////////////////////////////////////`

Comment: That's similar to asking why /index.htm, /index.html and / return the same page. I have seen both, http clients and http servers that would not be able to handle these multishlashes. It depends on how the client and server are implemented and configured.